# How to trick my network into believing it sent a GET request to an URL while it is localhost?

Tags: networking, http, https, fiddler

Let's assume I send a GET request for the URL: https://www.example.com/
Is it possible to trick my network into thinking that it received a reply from said URL while it's actually coming from localhost? And if yes, how? I've only seen a tool called "Fiddler2" being able to do this via the "AutoResponder" feature. However, since I use Linux (specifically Kubuntu) and FiddlerEverywhere costs money, I'm looking for a free alternative that I could set up myself. If anyone knows how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't fear getting your hands dirty and know a bit of Python, then mitmproxy is very powerful.

Comment: You can simply use */etc/hosts* to direct requests for *www.example.com* to 127.0.0.1 but you'll need a web server or proxy to accept the request.

Comment: @Zac67 changing domain addresses via /etc/hosts (or DNS in general) will work for plain HTTP, but doing that for HTTPS requires significantly more setup, because your localhost web server can't provide a trusted HTTPS certificate for example.com.

Comment: I wouldn't call that *significantly more setup*, it's "just" a self-signed certificate and according trust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've developed a tool to do exactly this: [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech/).

Internally it's an intercepting HTTPS proxy, like Fiddler etc, so you can intercept any traffic by configuring HTTP Toolkit as your proxy for the client you're interested in. It also has quick one-click setup buttons for browsers, terminals, Android devices, etc, and everything works on Linux (in addition to Windows & Mac).

Once you're intercepting a client, you can breakpoint its requests and respond directly in the app to send responses without ever forwarding the requests to the real server. You can also forward requests upstream to the real server, and then manually modify the response before it's sent to the client, if you prefer.

All of that works out of the box in the free version, using manual breakpointing for testing & debugging. If you're looking to set up more complex fully automated rules, those are available with a [Pro upgrade](https://httptoolkit.tech/get-pro/), which helps fund ongoing development.

All of HTTP Toolkit is 100% is open-source, and for programmatic use cases the internals are published as a convenient standalone JavaScript library called [Mockttp](https://github.com/httptoolkit/mockttp), which you can also use to do this. Using Mockttp you can build your own intercepting proxy in a few lines of code, and define precise logic for fake responses any way you like. There's an introduction guide to that with examples here: https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/javascript-mitm-proxy-mockttp/.